# Custom login in laravel 7 without model

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

What would be the best way to implement authentication in laravel if I already have my users table (I imported it through an sql dump) and cannot modify its structure?

I don't have any model for this new table. Also the fields in my custom table are different from the default user table from laravel (It doesn't have rememberToken(), createdAt, updatedAt).

These are the changes I made to auth.php:

```
'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'token',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
],

'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'database',
        'table' => 'users',
    ],
],
```

Comment: your login is using email and password?

Comment: Yes. The fields are 'mail' and 'pasword'. Also, the password is hashed with sha512.

Comment: You always can create a custom model and define any property you need, including table name using `protected $table = 'your_table';`

Comment: Please note that high speed hashes like SHA are generally considered insufficient for password hashing. Instead use [`password_hash()`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [`password_verify()`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php)